# Call to fopen fails in quickwatch window in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging

I am unable to call function "fopen" in "QuickWatch" in the debugger in [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005). Every time it says the following in QuickWatch window.

```
fopen("temp1.txt","w+")
```

And it gives the following error.

> Error: symbol "fopen" not found

I checked using [Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) that definition of "fopen" is coming from "msvcr80d.dll". I also checked that menu *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Modules* is showing that symbol information for this DLL file is being loaded as following:

**DLL path**: C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b\msvcp80d.dll

**The [PDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) file is loaded from**: C:\Windows\symbols\dll\msvcp80d.i386.pdb

Just as for an attempt, I added the path for "Symbol Load Information" as "C:\user\Install\VS2005\VC\ce\Dll\x86\". I was hoping that this PDB file would have a "fopen" symbol, and it would let me call "fopen" from the debugger. But still the symbol information is loaded from the above location only.

Is there anything else I can try in settings with Visual Studio? Or anything else, perhaps like forcing Visual Studio to pick the "msvcr80d.lib" instead of the corresponding DLL file. I have seen it working at our times, and unfortunately I can not try the later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I wasn't aware that one could call functions in any debugger window in any VS version.

Comment: @ChrisO : yes we can call and it is very helpful actually. For example, I might want to dump the information about failing/crashing instance of class object. Usually people write helper routines for this and call them on the fly in debugger when needed. Debuggers support this. In the above case too, I didn't face the issue for calling "fopen" in GDB.

Comment: @ChrisO : In the current version, VS2005, also I am able to call any user-defined function. It is only system library functions, I am not able to call. For them it says, symbol not found.